# Restructure array to join elements from 3rd position to end of array and store as 3rd element

Tags: php, arrays, merge, slice, implode

I have arrays like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => 85
    [1] => 85167920
    [2] => ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONIC
    [3] => DEVICES
    [4] => FOR
    [5] => REPELLING
    [6] => INSECTS
    [7] => (E.G.MOSQUITOES
    [8] => ETC)
)
```

and

```
Array(
   [0] => 85
   [1] => 851680
   [2] => ELECTRIC
   [3] => HEATING
   [4] => RESISTORS
)
```

I want arrays like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => 85
    [1] => 851680
    [2] => ELECTRIC HEATING RESISTORS
)
```

and

```
Array(
    [0] => 85
    [1] => 85167920
    [2] => ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONIC DEVICES FOR REPELLING INSECTS (E.G.MOSQUITOES ETC)
)
```

I am not sure about what method to use: merge / combine / push.
What should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array_slice()` and `implode()`

Method: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7aebd3038a31a99168ab5f0daeb036f305cfe1ce))

```
$array=[85,851680,'ELECTRIC','HEATING','RESISTORS'];
$array=[$array[0],$array[1],implode(' ',array_slice($array,2))];
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 85,
  1 => 851680,
  2 => 'ELECTRIC HEATING RESISTORS',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine :

```
<?php

$a = [
           85, 
           85167920, 
           'ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONIC', 
          'DEVICES', 
           'FOR', 
           'REPELLING', 
           'INSECTS', 
          '(E.G.MOSQUITOES 
           ETC)' 
];
$b = [ 
           85,
           851680,
           'ELECTRIC',
           'HEATING',
           'RESISTORS'
];

$aa = array_slice($a, 0,2);
$aa[] = implode(' ',array_slice($a, 2));

$bb = array_slice($b, 0,2);
$bb[] = implode(' ',array_slice($b, 2));

print_r($aa);
echo '<br>';
print_r($bb);

?>
```

Comment: :D :D m here to help out, u had a process n i had mine.

Comment: No, your process is a duplicate of my earlier posted one.  Your answer is page bloat and it will likely be downvoted further as it is a late duplicate.

Comment: m sorry , but i don't see it as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code,

```
<?php
$array = array();
$temp_array = array();
$temp_str_array=array();
$array[]=85;
$array[]=85167920;
$array[]='ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONIC';
$array[]='DEVICES';
$array[]='FOR';
$array[]='REPELLING';
$array[]='INSECTS';
$array[]='(E.G.MOSQUITOES';
$array[]='ETC)';
foreach($array as $k=>$values){
    if($k<=1){
        $temp_array[$k]=$values;
    }
    else{
        $temp_str_array[]=$values;
    }
    if(count($array)==($k+1)){
        $temp_array[3]=implode(" ",$temp_str_array);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp_array);
?>
```

Output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 85
    [1] => 85167920
    [3] => ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONIC DEVICES FOR REPELLING INSECTS 
    (E.G.MOSQUITOES ETC)
)
```